# How to run javascript from server

Tags: javascript, server, background

I am trying to make a project,which connects to UBER api.Then fetches the data about multipliers from the last week and uploads it to the google drive.Everything is working fine,when I open this program in the tab of my browser.But I would like to run this code from the server.So that my computer can be turned off and my program would still upload data to google drive.
Could anyone give me some hint about how to do it?So that my JS program would run constantly from server?
I've already tried uploading my project to heroku,but it still needed to have my tab opened.Also I've tried to upload whole mi index.html+script to server .But it also did not work.
I would be really thankful for your help.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To run javascript on the server-side you have to use **[node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)**.

Keep in mind that node doesn't have XMLHttpRequest so you will have to rewrite some of your code, or use a wrapper like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest.